# Serviço do Windows com Python

Tags: python, services

sou novo com python, e estou querendo criar um serviço do windows usando a linguagem, vi que existe bibliotecas para q seja feito ate encontrei alguns codigos de exemplo e tentei adaptar, quando uso 'python nome.py install' o serviço instala, mas no gerenciador de serviços do windows ele não inicia sempre apresenta

O Windows não pôde iniciar o serviço ServTeste em Computador local.

Erro 1053: O serviço não respondeu à requisição de início ou controle em tempo hábil.

O intuito do programa é baixar pacotes de atualizações dentro da pasta de instalação de um programa ja instalado, precisa rodar como serviço para que tenha essa verificação automática

antecipo agradecimentos

```
import win32service

import win32serviceutil

import win32event

from model.Orientador import * #retorna strings com os diversos endereços necessarios por onde a aplicação precisa percorrer

from connections.Rede import Transferencia #uso de ftp

from model.Leitoras import * #Leitora de txt

from connections.Handler import Handler #conexao com BD

import time

from connections.teste import *

import os.path

class ServPython(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):

    _svc_name_ = "ServTeste"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Serv - Teste (Servicoteste)"
    _svc_description_ = ""


    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)



    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import servicemanager

        os.chdir('..')
        os.chdir('..')

        pasta_raiz = os.getcwd()
        pasta_inicio = pasta_raiz + 'pasta onde fica o arquivo .py'
        os.chdir(pasta_inicio) #função usada sempre que um objeto de outra pasta é usado

        localini = Orienta.local(4)
        os.chdir(pasta_inicio)

        bancolocal = LeitorTxt.leitor(2, localini)
        os.chdir(pasta_inicio)

        execucao = 0  #usado antes para determinar looping infinito
        rc = None

        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:  # looping infinito

            t0 = time.sleep(1)  #####controle de tempo de verificação

            localatualizacao = Orienta.local(2)  ## endereço da pasta de atualizacao
            os.chdir(pasta_inicio)

            arquivotemporario = Transferencia.pacote(2, localatualizacao)  ##arquivo de controle para verificar se a versão é diferente ou não
            os.chdir(pasta_inicio)

            versaodisponivel = LeitorTxt.leitorFtp(1, localatualizacao)  # leitura do arquivo de controle
            versaodisponivel = int(versaodisponivel)

            arquivojabaixado = localatualizacao + '\\' + str(versaodisponivel) + '.rar'  ##endereço para verificar se o arquivo ja não existe

            if os.path.exists(arquivojabaixado):  ##verificação

                arquivoexiste = 'S'
            else:

                arquivoexiste = 'N'

            busca = Handler.query('select versaoatual from tab253', bancolocal)  ##consulta de versao no banco
            temporario = busca[0]
            versaolocal = temporario[0]
            os.chdir(pasta_inicio)

            if versaodisponivel > versaolocal and arquivoexiste == 'N':  ##inicio de download de pacotes se for diferente
                pacote = Transferencia.pacote(1, localatualizacao)
                os.chdir(localatualizacao)
                os.rename('atualizacao.rar', str(versaodisponivel) + '.rar')  ##renomeando arquivo
                os.chdir(pasta_inicio)

            execucao = 0  # garante looping infinito

            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)



            def SvcStop(self):

                self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)

                win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(ServPython)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive esse mesmo problema recentemente, tentei utilizar o Pyinstall e outras ferramentas mas sem sucesso. A unica ferramenta que me atendeu de forma satisfatória foi a [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Você instala ela via `npm` no node.js e o serviço começa a rodar, utilizando o comando:

```
$ pm2 start app.js
```

Com Python seria:

```
$ pm2 start __init__.py
```

O serviço já começa a rodar e pode fechar o console que ele continua rodando, como ser fosse em console.